# Handling User Sessions using Facebook Javascript SDK 

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

I have searched a lot regarding this issue and have not succeeded until now.
I would like to have a complete script that handles user sessions effectively, right from the Login to the point where when the user logs out of facebook in some other tab, the application should track the status change and ask the user to Relogin. Can anyone help me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

See the Facebook JavaScript SDK -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/